# Multi-lingual rss feed question

Tags: rss, multilingual

I paid a developer to write a script to generate an RSS feed for multiple languages for a site.  My only question is that when I go to the URL for the XML that's generated, it doesn't show up in Korean, it shows up like...

```
&amp;iacute;&amp;dagger;&amp;nbsp;&amp;euml;&amp;bdquo;&amp;circ;&amp;euml;&amp;uml;&amp;frac14;&amp;iacute;&amp;Scaron;&amp;cedil;&amp;euml;&amp;yen;&amp;frac14; &amp;igrave;&amp;curren;&amp;euro;&amp;euml;&amp;sup1;&amp;bdquo;&amp;iacute;&amp;bull;&amp;tilde;&amp;euml;&amp;tilde;
```

I've never worked with multiple languages before, is there a header or something that should be added to this page?  Is the `<language>` tag supposed to read `<language>ko-kr</language>` for Korean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are so called HTML entities. No header will change anything, as Korean characters (as well all the others) should be UTF-8 encoded. That's actually standard character encoding for XML and basically that's what should be used for multilingual RSS or ATOM feeds.